# Django DeleteView derived CBV is deleting my object without showing confirm delete page

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I am using Django 3.2

I have a model Foo, and I have written a CBV to allow for deletion. This is what my CBV looks like:

##### /path/to/foo/view.py

```
class FooDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Foo
    slug_url_kwarg = 'identifier'
    slug_field = 'identifier'    
    success_url = reverse_lazy('homepage')


    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        identifier = self.kwargs[self.slug_field]
        return self.model.objects.get(identifier=identifier)

    def test_func(self):
        photo = self.get_object()
        return self.request.user == foo.owner


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> HttpResponse:
        # foo object is needed for some other logic (audit trail etc.)
        foo = self.get_object()
        
        # ....
        

        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

#### /path/to/foo/templates/foo/templates/foo_confirm_delete

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block page_title %}Foo deletion Confirmation {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'myapp:foo-delete' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        Are you sure you want to delete this item?<br>
        <br>
        <strong>{{ object }}</strong>
        {{ form.errors }}
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="confirm_delete" value="confirm_delete">
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</input>
            <a href="../">Cancel</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Why is my `foo_confirm_delete.html` form not being displayed to give me a chance to cancel - before the object is deleted? How do I fix this?

Comment: Why do you override `FooDeleteView.post`? I think `DeleteView` should take care of it.

Comment: @KryštofŘeháček: I need to record the deletion activity (related to reputation scoring system), and also, to add a message to `contrib.messages` to be displayed to the user on deletion. I actually removed the `foo.delete()` from my post method (and still called `super().post(...)` - but the foo object still got deleted with no warning.

Comment: Can you provide the link that is created to reach the `FooDeleteView`?

Comment: Is the initial delete link making a GET request? It should be like `<a href="{% url 'myapp:foo-delete' %}"></a>` in order for any confirm pages to appear.